# Is there a way to "neutralize" the sweet vanilla smell of almond milk?

Tags: sauce, vegan, almond-milk

I always buy Alpro's vegetable milks that don't have a sweet smell (I think it's vanilla). This week I couldn't find it. I want to make a white sauce for potatoes. Is there anything I can do to improve this smell?

Comment: Maybe something acidic? Lemon?